# What is the right and most efficient way to access the last 30 seconds of a mpeg ts stream using Python?

Tags: python, numpy, ffmpeg

I have a mpeg ts stream from my dvb card that is written to disk. I'd like to access this stream continuously (last 30 seconds, every 20 seconds) from Python.

I am not looking for a complete solution here, but rather some ideas how to accomplish this in the most efficient manner with regards to CPU and RAM usage.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!